# Selecting every 2nd div inside other div

Tags: javascript, css

```
<div id="random numbers">
<div class="column-1"><a href="..."></a></div>
<div class="column-1"><a href="...">this value I want to change</a></div>
<div class="column-1"><a href="..."></a></div>
</div>
```

from earlier advice, I have this code:

```
var elements = document.querySelectorAll('.column-1 a');
for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
  elements[i].outerHTML = "OVERRIDDEN";
  }
```

the issue I'm having is that this replaces each `<a` inside each div `<div id="random numbers">`), while I would like it only to replace the second column-1 inside each random numbers div.

thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

document.querySelectorAll('.column-1 a')[1].outerHTML = "OVERRIDDEN";

Answer (score 0):

Just work with `i`

```
var elements = document.querySelectorAll('.column-1');
for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
  if(i%2) { // override 2nd, 4th, etc.
    elements[i].outerHTML = "OVERRIDDEN";
  }
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/ishukshin/av6t6kxz/

Comment: or, `for (var i = 1; i < elements.length; i+=2) { elements[i].outerHTML = "OVERRIDDEN"; }`